# Error with polyglossia using spanish and \sen

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, spanish

I'm trying to switch from `pdflatex` to `lualatex`. When I use `polyglossia` using Spanish with `\sen` it does not work well. Several tries, no success. MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\makeatletter
%\appto\inlineextras@spanish{\renewcommand\sin{\qopname \relax m{sen}}}
%\appto\blockextras@spanish{\renewcommand\sin{\qopname \relax m{sen}}}
%\makeatother
%\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}
%\renewcommand{\sin}{\operatorname{sen}}
%\renewcommand{\sen}{\operatorname{sen}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\cos^2 + \sin^2x&=1\\
\cos^2 + \sen^2x&=1\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: From your question, I think you are assuming `babel` doesn’t work with `lualatex`, but it certainly works (and with `xelatex`, too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the `spanishoperators` option, but also make `\sen` the same as `\sin`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spanishoperators=all]{spanish}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\appto\inlineextras@spanish{\NewCommandCopy\sen\sin}
\appto\blockextras@spanish{\NewCommandCopy\sen\sin}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\cos^2x + \sin^2x&=1\\
\cos^2x + \sen^2x&=1\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: spanishoperators will do the trick. Thank you very much to everybody

Answer (score 4):

If using [babel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) instead of [polyglossia](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) is an option for you, the following code should be of interest. Note that both `\sin` and `\sen` now output "sen" in upright (aka "roman") letters.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\usepackage{unicode-math} % optional

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}     % defines '\sen' macro
\let\sin\relax                  % undefine '\sin' first
\DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{sen} % redefine '\sin'

\begin{document}
$\sin x$, $\sen x$
\end{document}
```